# Laravel - Architecture question for multilingual wwebsite with control panel and more

Tags: laravel, architecture, content-management-system, erp

Good afternoon all,

I am relatively new to Laravel and software design. Recently my position within the company changed and I will now be developing the website (both back and front end) plus some utilities (forms, submitting data to database for ISO 9001 compliance etc.).

This will be an ongoing project as part of my role, so I expect this "task" to last 2 years. I have a decent understadning of PHP, HTML, CSS and have started to study Laravel.

The objective is to have within 1 year a:

- CMS with CRUD capabilities for a multilingual website (or better various domains .cn, .it, .com will point to the locale version of the same laravel instance)
- CMS back and front end for the website + blog
- A bunch of utilities that are more concerned with submitting forms, logging data etc.

The question is: "What's the best way to GLUE all togehter?"

Should I have two separate Laravel installations (one for the website and one for the "forms/ERP part"? Or can I do that all with one installation? Pros? Cons? Things to consider?

I have a decent idea on how to implement the single components, just struggling to think long-term consequences and how to structure it all.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood , You don't need to build more than one Laravel project .

You'll use Laravel MVC and sperate the folders in view , controllers For Admin (CRM) , and front .

Some packages you'll need :-

**For Mutli-langugae**

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

**For roles and permissions**

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

**For General Settings Crud**

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings

BTW , you should know how to deal with blades which is powerful templating engine that is included with Laravel :- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade

And you should know the basics of using the Mysql and the Elquoent Model in Laravel :- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent

That's will be a good start for your task .

Comment: Any reason why it might be better to have two different ones? I mean from a security or structure point of view or I am pretty solid with Laravel 9?

Comment: if you're using SPA , maybe you can use it , but there's no security concerns